# How to get EC2 Instances IpAddress of a cloudformation stack using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, aws-powershell

I want to list down IpAddresses of EC2 Instances of a CloudFormation stack using PowerShell. I'm trying the below command but it is not returning IpAddress.

```
Get-CFNStackResourceList -StackName 'teststack' -LogicalResourceId 'EC2Instance' -region 'eu-west-1'
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to check with

- [Get-EC2InstanceStatus](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Get-EC2InstanceStatus.html) (AWS Tools for Windows PowerShell)
- or [DescribeInstanceStatus](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ApiReference-query-DescribeInstanceStatus.html) (Amazon EC2 Query API)

Basic example:

```
PS C:\> Get-EC2InstanceStatus -InstanceId i-12345678

AvailabilityZone : us-west-2a
Events           : {}
InstanceId       : i-12345678
InstanceState    : Amazon.EC2.Model.InstanceState
Status           : Amazon.EC2.Model.InstanceStatusSummary
SystemStatus     : Amazon.EC2.Model.InstanceStatusSummary

PS C:\> $status = Get-EC2InstanceStatus -InstanceId i-12345678
PS C:\> $status.InstanceState

Code    Name
----    ----
16      running
```

Then, collect all IPv4 addresses like this:

```
$EC2Instances = Get-EC2Instance

foreach($instance in $EC2Instances.Instances){
  $addresses = "";
  foreach($networkInterface in $instance.NetworkInterfaces){
    $addresses = $addresses, $networkInterface.PrivateIpAddresses.PrivateIpAddress -join ","
  }
  "$($instance.InstanceID): $($addresses.Trim(','))"    
}
```

Furthermore, it might be helpful to count the instances like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27236242/8291949):

```
$filterRunning = New-Object Amazon.EC2.Model.Filter -Property @{Name = "instance-state-name"; Value = "running"}
$runningInstances = @(Get-EC2Instance -Filter $filterRunning)
# Count the running instances
$runningInstances.Count
```

See also: AWS Developer Blog - [Scripting your EC2 Windows fleet using Windows PowerShell and Windows Remote Management](https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/developer/scripting-your-ec2-windows-fleet-using-windows-powershell-and-windows-remote-management/)

Comment: I found another way to solve my problem.. I made my CloudFormation to Output the Name of the Auto Scaling Group and I used the below command in the PowerShell Script to get the IP's of EC2 Instances.

$iplist = (Get-ASAutoScalingInstance | ? {$_.AutoScalingGroupName -eq $ASGName} | select -expandproperty InstanceId | Get-EC2Instance | select -expandproperty RunningInstance ).PublicIpAddress